# Microsoft Sharepoint is not supported with version

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, powershell

I have Windows server 2012 installed.

When I open up Powershell ISE I get an error while using SharePoint 2010. IT works  fine with SharePoint 2010 management Shell.

> Microsoft SharePoint  is not supported with version 4.0.30319.34014

So far I have run the
1) SharePoint.ps1 script in the C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration folder in Windows Powershell ise

2) Ran powershell -version 2 in Windows powershell ise

3) C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe " C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration\sharepoint.ps1"

Comment: Is it SharePoint 2010 or 2013?

Comment: It is Sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 2):

Their is compatibility issue with SharePoint 2010 and version 4. You need to switch back to version 2.

Note: This will not uninstall version 3, it will simply launch a new powershell instance that uses version 2.

To work around this issue, change the Target field value for SharePoint 2010 Management Shell. To do this, follow these steps:

- Click Start, and then right-click SharePoint 2010 Management Shell.
- Click Properties.
- Click the Shortcut tab in the SharePoint 2010 Management Shell
  Properties window.
- Input the following value in the Target field:

  C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Version 2.0 -NoExit " & ' C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration\sharepoint.ps1 ' "

[SharePoint 2010 Management Shell does not load with Windows PowerShell 3.0](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2796733)

Check this: [SharePoint 2010, server 2012 and Powershell 3: Microsoft SharePoint is not supported with version 4.0.30319.17626 of the Microsoft .Net Runtime](http://tomvangaever.be/blogv2/2012/07/sharepoint-2010-server-2012-and-powershell-3-microsoft-sharepoint-is-not-supported-with-version-4-0-30319-17626-of-the-microsoft-net-runtime/)

Comment: I dont get an issue when i open sharepoint 2010 management shell but i get the above error when i open windows powershell ise

Comment: yes that is the issue with Windows powershell ISE...check both blogs

Comment: So how do I fix the issue

Comment: workaround already mentioned( provided by MSFT), You have to input the target value.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work with Powershell ISE. I've pasted in the "target" above, but it was set to exactly that before.

The correct information is that one can't run Powershell ISE version 2 after version 3 is installed (so on the 2012 server I use, this can't be done). Here is a relevant link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919862/start-powershell-ise-with-the-2-0-runtime